# SQL displaying percentage

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get SQL to display what percent of the eligible courses a user has passed.

Using the below query the results I get back are either 0 or 100%,

```sql
Select passed_courses, eligible_courses, (passed_courses/eligible_courses) * 100 as 'PERCENT'
FROM Training
```

| passed | eligible | PERCENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 100 |
| 3 | 6 | 0 |
| 4 | 6 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 0 |

Comment: did you try multiplying by 100 first `(passed_courses * 100 /eligible_courses)` ? I guess if the column type is *Integer* then the db will execute an euclidean division(example: 4/5 is 0 and the rest is 4) so multiplying by 100 first should solve it

Comment: which Dbms are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are dividing integers, try this:

```
SELECT passed_courses, eligible_courses,
       (CAST(passed_courses AS DECIMAL) / eligible_courses) * 100 as "PERCENT"
FROM Training;
```